# How to make a vector parameter with a non-specific type?

Tags: c++, function, vector, types

I'm aiming to create a C++ function which takes a vector parameter and, independent on the type given to the vector, print out the contents of the vector on by one, next to each other. The code below works for vectors of type `<int>`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using std::vector;

void PrintVect(vector <int> vect) {
    for (unsigned i = 0; i < vect.size(); i++) {
        std::cout << vect[i];
    }
}

int main() {

    vector <int> nums = {1, 2, 3};

    PrintVect(nums);
}
```

What change should I make to make it work with any type of vector?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Simple: make it a template function. Also you should be passing the vector by (const) reference to avoid unnecessary copies.

```cpp
template<typename T, typename Allocator>
void PrintVect(const std::vector<T, Allocator> &vect)
{
    for (const auto &i : vect) std::cout << i;
}
```

Comment: This does, of course, assume there is a suitable `operator<<()` overload for streaming a `T` to a `std::ostream`.    For fundamental types (`int`, etc) and some - not all - types in the standard library, this assumption is true.   For types for which it is not true, such a solution will not compile.  It doesn't make sense to be able to stream all types so it is necessary to deliberately implement streaming capability when it is needed.

Comment: @Peter I felt that was implied by the word "Print"

Answer (score 3):

`vector<int>` and vectors with different element type, e.g. `vector<string>`, have different types and do not share a common "supertype", which you could pass to your "print all sort of vectors function".

You can, however, define a template function that takes the vector's element type as template parameter; by that, the compiler will automatically generate a dedicated print-function for each element type you actually use:

```
template <typename T>
void PrintVect(const vector <T> &vect) {
    for (auto val : vect) {
        std::cout << val << " ";
    }
    std::cout << endl;
}

int main() {

    vector <int> nums = {1, 2, 3};
    PrintVect(nums);

    vector <string> strings = { "one", "two", "three" };
    PrintVect(strings);
}
```

Note the `const` and the `&` in `void PrintVect(const vector <T> &vect)`; as the vector is not modified, passing a copy of the vector would be superfluous; so the parameter type should be a const reference, i.e. `const &`.

Answer (score 2):

You can make a template function which will in effect create a copy of the function for every `vector<type>` you use with it.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

// take the vector by reference to not copy the whole vector
// make it const to promise to not change the vector
template<typename T>
void PrintVect(const std::vector<T>& vect) {
    for(const auto& val : vect)
        std::cout << val;
}

int main() {
    std::vector<int> nums = {1, 2, 3};

    PrintVect(nums);
}
```

To make it even simpler to use, you can turn your function into an overload for `operator<<`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

template<typename T>
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const std::vector<T>& vect) {
    for(const auto& val : vect)
        os << val;
    return os;
}

int main() {
    std::vector<int> nums = {1, 2, 3};

    std::cout << nums << "\n";
}
```